# How to compare Strings & ints in Generic Using comparable C#

Tags: c#, generics, compareto

I have tried to use IComparable and researched but I cannot figure out why this will not work.
I want to compare strings and ints but I don't understand how to use the ICompareable interface to do compareTo on a type of Generic.

How do I implement the CompareTo to handle Generics?

```
public class QuickSort : IComparable
{
    public static int Partition<T>(ref T[] arr, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int i = lo + 1;
        int j = hi;
        while (j > i)
        {
            while (arr[i].) // <- Cannot apply CompareTo
                i++;
            while (arr[j] > arr[lo])
                j--;

            Swap(ref arr[i], ref arr[j]);
        }

        Swap(ref arr[lo], ref arr[j]);

        return j;

        }
}
```

Comment: Filip, did any of the answers help?

Comment: @Andrew yeah they helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that `T` can be compared, the compiler can't know otherwise that type to expect. This way you can use `CompareTo` for both your conditions:

```
public class QuickSort
{
    public static int Partition<T>(T[] arr, int lo, int hi) where T : IComparable
    {
        int i = lo + 1;
        int j = hi;
        while (j > i)
        {
            while (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[lo]) == 0)
                i++;
            while (arr[j].CompareTo(arr[lo]) > 0) // means arr[j] > arr[lo]
                j--;

            Swap(ref arr[i], ref arr[j]);
        }

        Swap(ref arr[lo], ref arr[j]);

        return j;
    }
}
```

Also, I don't think you want to compare different `QuickSort` instances, so I removed its interface.

Update: Based on Hawkmooon's comment, I took a second look at your method and thought its signature can be even simpler:

```
    public static int Partition(IComparable[] arr, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int i = lo + 1;
        int j = hi;
        while (j > i)
        {
            while (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[lo]) == 0)
                i++;
            while (arr[j].CompareTo(arr[lo]) > 0)
                j--;

            Swap(ref arr[i], ref arr[j]);
        }

        Swap(ref arr[lo], ref arr[j]);

        return j;
    }
```

I think your code may be missing something. Just in case, [here you have a full C# example of a working quicksort method](http://snipd.net/quicksort-in-c).

Comment: Great answer.  Also note that you don't need to make the "arr" parameter "ref" as the array members can be modified regardless of the way "arr" is passed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify that your `T` implements `IComparable`. Change the declaration of your method to look like that:

```
public static int Partition<T>(ref T[] arr, int lo, int hi) where T : IComparable
```

Also you can’t compare your items like `arr[i] > arr[j]`. You need to call `CompareTo()` and check if it’s more then zero, less then zero or equals zero:

```
while(arr[i].CompareTo(arr[high]) > 0)
```

(that will means that `arr[i] > arr[high]` in your case.)

And most likely you don’t need to implement `IComparable` on the `QuickSort` class. `IComparable` need to be implemented for those items that will be compared, not for the comparator class itself.

Comment: Would I need to implement CompareTo myself if I declare I use the interface?

Comment: But do you really want to compare instances of `QuickSort`?? I highly doubt it. If you add the interface, of course you will have to implement your `CompareTo` method. Otherwise it won't even compile.

Comment: You don’t need to implement `CompareTo()` if you’re going to working with strings, ints and other classes that inherit from `IComparable` interface. If you’re going to work with an array of your custom items `MyItem`, then you would want to implement `IComparable` interface directly to the items you will compare (not to the `QuickSort` class itself).

Comment: Also, as far as I know, in QuickSort you have to take a `pivot` point in the middle of your array and compare `arr[i].CompareTo(arr[pivot])` instead of `a[i].CompareTo(a[j])` or `a[i].CompareTo(a[low (high?)])`.